# How can I do case insensitive string search with Linq and SQL Server?

Tags: linq, string, search, case-insensitive

Here is my current code for searching tags:

```
    public JsonResult TagSearch(string term) {
        if (term == null || term == "")
            return Json("");

        var tags = (from t in _session.All<Tag>() where t.Name.Contains(term) select t.Name).Take(6).ToArray();

        return Json(tags);
    }
```

How could I do case insensitive string search instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Contains() method is converted to case-insensitive operation in SQL. I think the code I posted **is** case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Is changing the collation of the column out of the question?

Answer (score -1):

Use the ToLower method. Like this:

```
var tags = (from t in _session.All<Tag>() where t.Name.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower()) select t.Name).Take(6).ToArray();
```