# Serialize to JSON with lower case property values

Tags: c#, unit-testing, json.net, moq

I have a operations layer that gets an Entity Framework database context injected into it.  I am writing unit tests against the operations layer by mocking the database context using Moq as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx).  The mocked data is stored in text files in JSON format, which are created from data in a real database since the data is a bit too complex to make up from scratch.

Everything's going well except for one little issue.  When testing some query functions, I'm having some trouble with case sensitivity.  When the application runs, it translates the LINQ queries into SQL; since `like %search value%` is case insensitive, the case of the search term doesn't matter.  But since the mocked data is being loaded from JSON and is not going through SQL, tests are failing when they shouldn't.

For example, I have two mocked records, one has a field value of 'Port Gamble A' and another has 'PORT GAMBLE B'.  A unit test that searches for 'gamble' fails to find either mocked record, and a search for 'Gamble' only finds one.

Right now, I'm just calling `.ToLower()` on the name field after deserializing to get around this, but there are many text fields in child objects I want to test searching on and calling `.ToLower()` on every single one is going to be a pain.  Manually editing the JSON to lower case everything is even worse.  I also don't want to change the LINQ query to call `.ToLower()` on the search term and database field because it seems silly to change a query just for unit tests, and it could have some performance consequences.

Is there a way to customize the serialization to force all string values to lower case?  I found plenty of examples of how to lower case the *property names*, but not the actual values.

**EDIT**: Well, that was easy.  For those interested in the solution:

Custom JSON converter for string values:

```
public class LowerCaseJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString().ToLower());
    }
}
```

Serialization of an EF entity using the `LowerCaseJsonConverter`:

```
using (TextWriter textWriter = File.CreateText(string.Format("..\\..\\Test Data\\Cleanup Site\\{0}.json", fileName)))
{
    using (JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(textWriter))
    {
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer()
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        };

        serializer.Converters.Add(new LowerCaseJsonConverter());
        serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your JSON Method and your unit test? or an example? if you can use contains in your comparison (if its C# / Linq) then I believe it is case insensitive as per this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314130/how-can-i-do-case-insensitive-string-search-with-linq-and-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using `Json.Net`, you just need to use a custom serializer and you can add whatever logic you want to property names AND values

http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/